How to setup a column menu button next to the header?
I'm working on a table that should have a column filter. This filter should be a multi select but since I don't want to use the native <select> element ( because it's intuitive and difficult to style ) I tried to create my own menu component.
Since this HTML code will be executed inside a container of an external system it's not possible to embed third party libraries ( e.g. components ) so I have to use plain HTML, CSS and JS.
This is what I have so far


function toggleMenu(buttonElement) {
  buttonElement.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("menu-content")[0].classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function toggleOption(optionElement) {
  optionElement.classList.toggle("selected");

  // !!!For testing purposes only!!!
  console.log(optionElement.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("option selected"));
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  background: gray;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  min-width: 500px;
}
<div>
  other content goes here
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>
        Col 2
        <span class="menu">
          <button onclick="toggleMenu(this)">Filter</button>
          <div class="menu-content hidden">
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 1</div>
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 2</div>
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 3</div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>Val 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  other content goes here
</div>



I think it's working as expected, but I need help with the CSS of the menu content. As you can see the container is not aligned with the button. How can I fix this?
If my approach can be improved ( e.g. simplified ) please let me know! :)

Your menu-content wrapper is missing a left, top etc. property. That is why it's not sitting next to it's parent menu.


function toggleMenu(buttonElement) {
  buttonElement.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("menu-content")[0].classList.toggle("hidden");
}

function toggleOption(optionElement) {
  optionElement.classList.toggle("selected");

  // !!!For testing purposes only!!!
  console.log(optionElement.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("option selected"));
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;

}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  background: gray;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  min-width: 500px;
}
<div>
  other content goes here
</div>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>
        Col 2
        <span class="menu">
          <button onclick="toggleMenu(this)">Filter</button>
          <div class="menu-content hidden">
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 1</div>
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 2</div>
            <div class="option selected" onclick="toggleOption(this)">Selectable option 3</div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>Val 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  other content goes here
</div>



